# React.js call recursive function in render

Tags: javascript, recursion, reactjs, jsx

Trying to display a hierarquical tree view with React.js

**My render method:**

```
render: function(){
  var self= this;
  return(
    <div className="panel panel-flat content-group-lg">
      <div className='panel-body'>
        <div className="tree">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Categorias</a>                  
                { self.printTree(this.state.tree_array) }                        
            </li>  
          </ul>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**and my printTree method:**

```
printTree: function(level){
  console.log(level);
  var self = this;
  var level_length = level.length;

  if(level_length >= 1){
    return(
      <ul>{
        level.map(function(category){
          return (
            <li key={category.fields.name}>
              <a href='#'>{category.fields.name}</a>
            </li>
            {self.printTree(category.sons_array)}
          )         
        })
      }</ul>
    )
  }
}
```

The printTree method receives an array that corresponds to a "level" of the tree. My goal is to 'print' each element of this level ( so I use the map to iterate over the array ) but also print any possible sublevels of the current element, so I tried to call the function recursively, passing the 'sons' of the current element as the new array parameter for the recursive call.

For some reason, calling:

> {self.printTree(category.sons_array)}

gives me: **Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1/gims-webapp/components/NavBar.js: Unexpected token (901:84)**

I'm using JSX and can't figure out what JSX is complaining about..

**EDIT:**

My final structure should look like this:

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give the full error please? (Instead of "...")

Comment: @Cohars I posted the relevant parts. The error is not that intuitive, but anyway i'll edit it.

Comment: i was expecting something else after `Unexpected token` :) and well, it's frustrating to see incomplete errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSX requires expects only **one** Root Node](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html), so this code:

```
return (
    <li key={category.fields.name}>
        <a href="#">{category.fields.name}</a>
    </li>
    {self.printTree(category.sons_array)}
);
```

Should be changed to:

```
return (
    <li key={category.fields.name}>
        <a href="#">{category.fields.name}</a>
        {self.printTree(category.sons_array)}
    </li>
);
```

Or it's like returning:

```
<li>
 ...
</li>
<ul>
 ...
</ul>
```

Which are several root nodes.

Comment: I think putting the recursive call inside the <li> would not satisfy my needs of the hierarchy structure. I edited my question with the desired structure. Can it be adapted?

Comment: Don't mind about it...your solution is correct..the structure can be build this way you told.. really apreciate your help...

Comment: Now if we want to show serial number in front of  each row, how to calculate `index` value in increment manner inside recursive method?

Answer (score 2):

If you paste your code to [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/), you will see where is error in your example – it is inside `level.map(...)`, because you should return only *one* react node in `map` method (but you have `<li >` + `self.printTree` there). You can put self.printTree inside this li:

```
level.map(function(category){
  return (
    <li key={category.fields.name}>
      <a href='#'>{category.fields.name}</a>
      {self.printTree(category.sons_array)}
    </li>
   );
 })
```

Comment: @Pavarine but in your example you have exactly the same – `li>a+ul`, where `ul` is result of `self.printTree`

Comment: Your right!!! Don't mind about it...the structure is exact the same! I accepted @Cohars answer cause he posted some minutes before you, but i really thank you for the help Alexandr!!